# Using AWS cognito to maintain multiple client users separately and tracking their usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS cognito and I am still exploring the service. I will explain my requirement below, Please help me understand if I can get it done using AWS Congnito.

My app will have multiple Clients and each client will have multiple users. So I want multiple separate login groups which will have its own users.

I want to be able to restrict a login from one place at a time. i.e. a same login creds should not be used at multiple places at a single point of time.

Please guide me on how I can achieve this using AWS cognito.